# Multiple docker containers running in same windows machine

Tags: docker, cassandra, apache-kafka

I have two Docker images: one that contains Kafka, the other containing Cassandra. I can run them successfully individually, but when trying to run them at the same time in the same machine, disk utilization goes to 100%, and Docker basically does not respond anymore (cannot run any Docker command, even `docker ps`). CPU and memory utilization are ok (6% and 26%).

It happened when I ran in my local machine, as well as a cloud instance of Windows with higher specs -- the same behavior is observed.

Any idea why? When running those containers individually they do not seem to be disk intensive on their own.

Comment: Are you using volume mounts for each containers data & log directories? If not, can you try?

Comment: for the container with cassandra - yes, on its data directory. i will try on both containers, and both data and log.

Comment: i mounted the volumes for data and logs for both containers and I can now run both containers at the same time without disk going to 100%! Thanks so much for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mounting the data and log directories of both containers did the trick - I can now run both containers concurrently on Windows.